# XML for Android Programming

Tags: android, xml

I just picked up the Android Apps for Absolute Beginners and I read the introduction, it turns out you have to know Java.... so I read Sam's Teach Yourself Java And 24 Hours and I thought I was ready to dive into Android programming. When I began reading the book I noticed there was a lot of XML stuff and I don't know XML.. my question is, how much XML do you have to know in order to write Android apps. Can someone recommend a book or resource that has information about XML and Android? I have about three years of Objective-C experience and a couple days of Java experience.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) to develop your Android applications, you actually do not necessarily need to know much XML, as nearly everything you'd usually do in XML can be done through the user interface too.

Comment: @Frxstrem The tools are great, but, to be honest, sometimes it's much easier to drop down to the raw XML to do something or other.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know much about XML. Most of what you need can be absorbed by imitation. You don't need to know much more than the basics of XML syntax. (An easy XML tutorial can be found at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp). An even briefer tutorial, as well as links to the W3Schools tutorial and other learning resources can be found at the [XML Introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XML_Introduction) page at the Mozilla Developer Network site.) As to concepts of how XML and Java work together in Android, I'd strongly recommend that you go through the [training material on XML](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html#q=xml) at the Android web site.

Answer (score 3):

OK so there are a few questions in here that need breaking down...

> "how much XML do you have to know in order to write Android apps"

You need to know the basics. XML is not a programming language (as I am sure you are aware) and is a markup language. If you have 3 years of C under your belt this will take you all of a day at most to get your head round if not less.

Read the W3 Schools guide to XML http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ it has everything you need.

> "it turns out you have to know Java.... so I read Sam's Teach Yourself
>   Java And 24 Hours and I thought I was ready to dive into Android
>   programming"

Your existing knowledge should serve you well but spending 3 days on a language may simply not be enough (unless you are amazing in which case i retract this statement). Java in my own opinion is quite as nice language to learn and you should pick it up quite quickly with a little time.

Have you read the [Android Developers documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html)? Read it well, it has lots and lots of help. Every time I seem to write an answer or comment I reference the documentation. Have you checked the [samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample)? I find learning by example/practically quite useful and far more engaging.

Answer (score 1):

You should see and learn developer.android.com for android developers. In this website, you'll know about XML s very well and they're also sample to understand. You don't need to think about that. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Please be aware** that this answer is mostly focused on Android application development using Android Studio and may not be true for other development tools and methods.

XML is a markup language used for styling Android applications, it is generally used as a means of separating the application’s styling from the actual logic - meaning that that the “image” and “functionality” of the application are separate and if one changes, the other does not have to.

**To develop an Android application, you don’t need to know XML, On Android's Developer website - it states that you can either style your application at runtime using Java or use XML.** Though a basic understanding of XML may come in handy for problem-solving.

And even if you wish to use XML to style your app - you don't need /an in-depth knowledge of it as you can simply use Android Studio’s Layout-Editor (only versions  2.3 or higher can do this) - which will allow you to style your application visually and generate the corresponding XML afterwards which you're free to edit if you please.

**Sources**

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#strings

Also see: 
 - TutorialsPoint's Android tutorial titled "Styles and Themes" 
 - W3Schools' XML tutorials. 
 - As well as any of the appealing links on Android's developer website, TutorialsPoint and off-course W3Schools websites.

Forgive me for any mistakes in this post and you're free to correct them, forgive me for my inability to provide all the relevant links (due to my low reputation) and I hope this helps at least someone.